# f:param with condition

Tags: java, jsf

I have `f:param` like below...

```
<f:param name="NDCID" value="#{selectedMedicationInfoBean.NDCID}"></f:param>
<f:param name="insuranceID" value="#{selectedMedicationInfoBean.insurance.id}"></f:param>
```

in few cases

```
#{selectedMedicationInfoBean.insurance.id}
```

comes null. Can we prevent it? I can't use turnery operator inside JSF Expression.

```
<f:param name="insuranceID" value="#{selectedMedicationInfoBean.insurance.id=null?'':selectedMedicationInfoBean.insurance.id}">
```

Is there any other way?

---

Functional Requirement : On page1 there is a link of `detail`. That will show detail information on page2.  As argument need to pass around 6 parameters. On the bases of those parameters detail page will generate information.

And issue is from those 6 parameters 2 can be null and cause of that below error come on view `page1`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.getCommandLinkOnClickScript(RenderKitUtils.java:934)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CommandLinkRenderer.getOnClickScript(CommandLinkRenderer.java:295)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CommandLinkRenderer.renderAsActive(CommandLinkRenderer.java:357)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CommandLinkRenderer.encodeBegin(CommandLinkRenderer.java:165)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:788)
org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.RendererUtils.renderChild(RendererUtils.java:433)
org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.RendererUtils.renderChildren(RendererUtils.java:419)
org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.RendererUtils.renderChild(RendererUtils.java:440)
```

Comment: What exactly is the functional requirement? So that we can understand better why it's a problem to send an empty/null parameter.

Comment: @BalusC , I have set my display name as 'Guruji' and that means 'A Teacher' but I can say you are my guruji for this JSF. Thanks a lot for your quick response.

Comment: Oh, you're using old JSF 1.2. In the future questions please mention exact JSF impl/version. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That exception is caused by an old Mojarra 1.2 bug which indeed manifests when the `<f:param>` value is `null`. It's been fixed in Mojarra 1.2_05 (or maybe one version before or after, not sure anymore, it's been more than 6 years ago). Just upgrade to latest Mojarra 1.2 which is currently already at [1.2_15](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/).

An alternative is to wrap it in a `<c:if>`, but that's plain ugly and also won't work if `selectedMedicationInfoBean` is been declared as the `var` of some parent `UIData` component.

```html
<c:if test="${not empty selectedMedicationInfoBean.insurance.id}">
    <f:param name="insuranceID" value="#{selectedMedicationInfoBean.insurance.id}" />
</c:if>
```

Another alternative is to specify a default value of `0` or `-1` instead and handle accordingly in the controller.

```html
<f:param name="insuranceID" value="#{not empty selectedMedicationInfoBean.insurance.id ? selectedMedicationInfoBean.insurance.id : -1}" />
```

Upgrading is the best option. You don't want to sit with a prehistoric library.

Comment: But as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418413/jsf-tdatatable-and-cforeach-looks-like-conflict if my link is inside datatable wont it be conflict?

Comment: If `selectMEdicationInfoBean` is definied by its `var` then yes it will cause a problem. You'd really need to upgrade to a newer Mojarra 1.2 version then.

Comment: yeah that's same it come from `var`... :(